# How to add pagination in wishlist index page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist, pagination

**I currently have issue that i have to add pagination in wishlist page**.
Is there a way to that since it isn't using a direct collection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm got it

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Wishlist\Block\Customer;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist
{

public function getWishlistItems()
{
    $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;

    if ($this->_collection === null) {
        $this->_collection = $this->_createWishlistItemCollection();
        $this->_prepareCollection($this->_collection);
    }
    $this->_collection
        ->setPageSize(6)
        ->setCurPage($page);

    return $this->_collection;
}

/**
 * This is needed to take the correct templates
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
}
```

Comment: How to add pagination links?